# Jquery UI Accordion changing element positions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

This the fiddle that hopefully will help me explain the problem that I have.  I am needing similar but yet different functionality.  http://jsfiddle.net/HgAQu/1856/

When you drag items, they indeed change positions, but I need another functionality. I need to swap positions.

As seen on example, when you move Item 1 on item 7, they dont change place. What happens is that Item one is the last, and item 7 is before item one

In another words before the move, we had: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

After that move we have:
2
3
4
5
6
7
1

And I need something like:
7
2
3
4
5
6
1

I am rendering all the elements and inserting them in accordion, so I can do pretty much everything with them.

I use following code to get first start move and end move. And those number are accurate. This is the code that I use:

```
accordion({
            header: "> div > h3",
            collapsible: true                      
        }).sortable({
              axis: "y",
              handle: "h3",                  
              start: function (event, ui) {
                  ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
              },
              stop: function (event, ui) {
                  var start =  ui.item.startPos;
                  var end = ui.item.index();
              }
        });
```

And that change is reflected on the model, I simply swap the values (backbone). But the UI(accordion) is not matching, since the problem I described above.

The solution that I have so far is to empty accordion and rerender/refresh it from model. That works.
I am wondering is there cleaner solution. Maybe that I render swapped elements and insert them manualy in the accordion. How difficult is that, what side problems may I get? Will I destroy the accordion functionality by manipulating elements manually?

Comment: You could change the title to swapping elements inside sortable, or something similar, because the current title doesn't reflect the actual problem. (just a suggestion, in case anyone else will have the same problem :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not perfect, but a good staring point : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/6bbBq/)

<strike>It only handles swapping 1-7,2-6,3-5 back an forth, but not 2 elements that are next to each other.(12,56,etc...), if you can't figure it out by tomorrow i'll give it a shot :)</strike>

**update**

My solution works, it is not the prettiest, though…

```
$("#sortable").sortable({

start: function (event, ui) {
    ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
},
stop: function (event, ui) {
    // handle swapping from bottom to top( 7 -> 1)
    if (ui.item.startPos > ui.item.index()) {
        // when items are next to each other, don't swap
        if ((ui.item.startPos - ui.item.index()) == 1) return;
        $("li").eq(ui.item.startPos).after(ui.item.next());
    } else {
        // when items are next to each other, don't swap
        if ((ui.item.index() - ui.item.startPos) == 1) return;
        // handle swapping from top to bottom(1 -> 7)
        $("li").eq(ui.item.startPos).before(ui.item.prev());
    }
}
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

Comment: That's it. Works as intended.